I want to use a React app (a game) inside another major React app (portfolio website). What is best way to implement such Micro-frontend
So, I want to add a Tic tac toe game(with Minimax algorithm) on the homepage of my portfolio website(React) as a showcase. But the game is going to be a seperate project(most probably with React) mainly because I want to make it a public github repository. I don't want to just copy-paste the code in the portfolio because I'd have to make changes in 2 places and I also want to implement Micro-frontend on a small scale to learn. Having never worked on Micro-frontends, I'm looking for advice on how I should do it.
For now, I'm going to make the game an NPM package but is there a better way?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
